# Integration testing of rabbit consumer in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, testing, rabbitmq

I have a question regarding the integration testing of the follwing rabbit mq service in spring boot:

```
package com.jchaaban.rabbitmqcosumer.service;
 
import com.jchaaban.rabbitmqcosumer.event.MessageCreatedEvent;
import com.jchaaban.rabbitmqcosumer.event.MessageDeletedEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
 
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = "${spring.rabbitmq.eventsQueueName}", id = "event-queue-listener")
public class RabbitMqReceiver {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMqReceiver.class);
 
    public List<MessageCreatedEvent> messageCreatedEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<MessageDeletedEvent> messageDeletedEvents = new ArrayList<>();
 
    @RabbitHandler
    public void receivedCreationEvent(MessageCreatedEvent event) {
        logger.info("Received Message Created Event: {}", event);
        messageCreatedEvents.add(event);
    }
 
    @RabbitHandler
    public void receivedCreationEvent(MessageDeletedEvent event) {
        logger.info("Thread Received Message Deleted Event: {}", event);
        messageDeletedEvents.add(event);
    }
}
```

I wrote this test class:

```
package com.jchaaban.rabbitmqcosumer.IT;
 
import com.jchaaban.rabbitmqcosumer.event.MessageCreatedEvent;
import com.jchaaban.rabbitmqcosumer.service.RabbitMqReceiver;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageDeliveryMode;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.QueueInformation;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.test.RabbitListenerTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.RabbitMQContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;
 
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
 
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
 
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@RabbitListenerTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class RabbitMqConsumerIntegrationTest {
 
    @Container
    private static final RabbitMQContainer rabbitMQContainer = new RabbitMQContainer(
            DockerImageName.parse(
                    "rabbitmq:management"
            )
    );
 
    public static final int MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 10000;
    public static final int WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS = 100;
 
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.eventsQueueName}")
    private String eventsQueue;
 
 
    @Autowired
    private RabbitMqReceiver rabbitMqReceiver;
 
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
 
    @Autowired
    private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;
 
    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
 
 
 
    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.host", rabbitMQContainer::getHost); 
        registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.port", () -> rabbitMQContainer.getMappedPort(5672));
    }
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        rabbitAdmin.purgeQueue(eventsQueue, true);
        registry.getListenerContainer("event-queue-listener").stop();
    }
 
 
    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        rabbitAdmin.purgeQueue(eventsQueue, true);
    }
 
    private int getMessageCountInQueue() {
        QueueInformation queueProperties = rabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(eventsQueue);
        if (queueProperties != null) {
            return queueProperties.getMessageCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }
 
    private void waitForMessagesToBeSentToQueue(int totalMessagesCount){
        long waitingTime = WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS;
        while (getMessageCountInQueue() < totalMessagesCount && waitingTime < MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS);
                waitingTime += WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
 
 
 
    private void waitForMessagesToBeConsumedFromQueue(){
        long waitingTime = WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS;
        while (getMessageCountInQueue() > 0 && waitingTime < MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS);
                waitingTime += WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
 
 
    private void startRabbitListener() {
        registry.getListenerContainer(
                "event-queue-listener"
        ).start();
    }
    @Test
    public void receiveEventSuccessfully() {
        MessageCreatedEvent event = new MessageCreatedEvent(1L, "Test message content" , LocalDateTime.now());
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(eventsQueue, event, messagePostProcessor -> {
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setHeader("__TypeId__", "MessageCreatedEvent");
            return messagePostProcessor;
        });
 
 
        waitForMessagesToBeSentToQueue(1);
 
        startRabbitListener();
 
        assertThat(rabbitMqReceiver.messageCreatedEvents).hasSize(1);
 
    }
    @Test
    public void receiveEventsInOrder() throws InterruptedException {
 
        for (long i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            MessageCreatedEvent event = new MessageCreatedEvent(i, "Test message content " + i , LocalDateTime.now());
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(eventsQueue, event, messagePostProcessor -> {
                messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
                messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setHeader("__TypeId__", "MessageCreatedEvent");
                return messagePostProcessor;
            });
 
        }
 
        waitForMessagesToBeSentToQueue(100);
 
        startRabbitListener();
 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
 
 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            assertThat(rabbitMqReceiver.messageCreatedEvents.get(i-1).getId()).isEqualTo(i);
        }
    }
}
```

in these tests i am trying to make sure that i can recieve events sent to the consumer and that the events are received in the same order they are published in (since i have only one consumer). I was trying to use something better than Thread.sleep(2000); in the second test to make sure that all events are consumed before asserting the order of them so i wrote the method:

```
    private void waitForMessagesToBeConsumedFromQueue(){
        long waitingTime = WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS;
        while (getMessageCountInQueue() > 0 && waitingTime < MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS);
                waitingTime += WAITING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
```

and change the test to look as follows:

```
@Test
    public void receiveEventSuccessfully() {
        MessageCreatedEvent event = new MessageCreatedEvent(1L, "Test message content" , LocalDateTime.now());
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(eventsQueue, event, messagePostProcessor -> {
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setHeader("__TypeId__", "MessageCreatedEvent");
            return messagePostProcessor;
        });
 
 
        waitForMessagesToBeSentToQueue(1);
 
        startRabbitListener();
 
        assertThat(rabbitMqReceiver.messageCreatedEvents).hasSize(1);
 
    }
    @Test
    public void receiveEventsInOrder() throws InterruptedException {
 
        for (long i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            MessageCreatedEvent event = new MessageCreatedEvent(i, "Test message content " + i , LocalDateTime.now());
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(eventsQueue, event, messagePostProcessor -> {
                messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
                messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setHeader("__TypeId__", "MessageCreatedEvent");
                return messagePostProcessor;
            });
 
        }
 
        waitForMessagesToBeSentToQueue(100);
 
        startRabbitListener();
 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
 
        waitForMessagesToBeConsumedFromQueue()
 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            assertThat(rabbitMqReceiver.messageCreatedEvents.get(i-1).getId()).isEqualTo(i);
        }
    }
```

but when i run the test even when the getMessageCountInQueue() returns 0 i see that not all events are consumed yet. I asked a developper working with me and he said that he would use the rabbitAdmin to send the events and then check with the rabbitAdmin if all events where consumed. I tried to do this but i did not found a sollution yet. Is there any solution for this problem?.

Thank you